# How to build Xamarin.Android Java Bindings Library in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)?

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, aar

I have an [Xamarin.Android Java Bindings Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/) and I need it to be built with VSTS. Where should I start?

And I will need the same for iOS.

Comment: Can you build the Android Binding Library Project locally?

Answer (score 0):

In general if you can build the project locally, then you can also build that in TFS/VSTS.

To build Xamarin.Android apps please see [Build your Xamarin app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/mobile/xamarin?view=vsts&tabs=vsts) for details. Just make sure the agent have the required capabilities.

> If you use VSTS, you can use a
>   Microsoft-hosted agent for both. If you use TFS, you will need a
>   self-hosted agent to build Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS.
>   Xamarin.iOS requires an agent running on macOS. Set up a self-hosted
>   agent and install Xamarin on the agent machine. The Xamarin version on
>   your development machine and build agent machine must be at least
>   4.0.3 for Windows and 5.10.3 for macOS.

Or you can directly run a command line build, reference this article : https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/xamarin/0003.html

Below blogs for your reference:

- [Creating Xamarin.Android Binding Library](https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-xamarin-android-binding-library/)
- [Building Xamarin.Android Apps in Team Services (VSTS) with Hosted
  Agents!](https://montemagno.com/building-xamarin-android-apps-in-team-services-vsts-with-hosted-vs-2017-agents/)